# Running the "First Electron App" wont show versions?

Tags: node.js, electron

I am following the [Electron quick start guide](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app), it works without any errors, but the output is not as described in the docs, the versions with `document.write` wont show up in the output.

This is my output:

```
Hello World!

We are using node , Chrome , and Electron .
```

My expected output would include the corresponding version numbers.

I have checked the GitHub page of the app, still the same, tried various StackOverflow answers but none worked for me.

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
We are using node <script>document.write(process.versions.node) </script>,
Chrome <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
and Electron <script>document.write(process.versions.electron) </script>.
</body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "electronapp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "main.js",
    "scripts": {
       "start": "electron ."
    },
    "author": "harsh",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "^5.0.2"
    }
}
```

**main.js**

```js
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    })

    mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        mainWindow = null
    })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin')
        app.quit()
})

app.on('activate', function () {
    if (mainWindow === null)
        createWindow()
})
```

I have Node globally installed, and Chrome is packaged with Electron, right?

Comment: Did you installed the dependencies?

Comment: Check my edit, i am not sure i answer your question.

Comment: Please, if you can, add your `main.js` and some screenshot of the output.

Comment: I have added the main.js file and the link to screenshot as you asked for.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you activate the Developer Tools, you should see error messages in the Console like such:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at index.html:11
```

You need to activate `nodeIntegration` and deactivate `contextIsolation` of the [BrowserWindow](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#browserwindow), so that the process running in the BrowserWindow ("renderer process") is allowed to access Node's `process` object.

```js
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
        nodeIntegration: true,
        contextIsolation: false
    }
})
```

(Before Electron 12, only the `nodeIntegration` key was needed, and the default value of `contextIsolation` was `false`.)

Comment: Thanks a ton! I am just getting started with electron and couldnt figure this out, also how do i activate developer tools?

Comment: If you have the default application menu, you can do it there. Or in code: `mainWindow.toggleDevTools()`.

Comment: So the uncaught reference error, would have shown up without your answer edit?

Comment: No. Sorry about the confusion. The error results from your original code (when `nodeIntegration` is not enabled). I included this in the answer to indicate how to catch similar issues. I moved this part up to make the order more logical.

Answer (score 3):

This is your file with correction

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
let mainWindow
function createWindow () {
    mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        webPreferences: {
            // I think you don't need this line
            // preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js') 
            nodeIntegration: true
        }
    })
    mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')
    mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
        mainWindow = null
    })
}
app.on('ready', createWindow)
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
app.on('activate', function () {
    if (mainWindow === null) createWindow()
})
```

Comment: This solves the issue, but I already accepted the answer by above user. As pointed out by you, what does that line do anyway? I dont have a file like that anyway. Does it do some preloading for the app, and can it be used by me to do any useful stuff in for the app?

Comment: Quote of Official doc `preload String (optional) - Specifies a script that will be loaded before other scripts run in the page. This script will always have access to node APIs no matter whether node integration is turned on or off. The value should be the absolute file path to the script. When node integration is turned off, the preload script can reintroduce Node global symbols back to the global scope.`

Answer (score 3):

After a lot of searching I found this:

```js
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
      webPreferences: {
          nodeIntegration: true,
          contextIsolation: false
     }
});
```

Note that `contextIsolation` was false by default until Electron 12, released Feb 2021.

Comment: I've formatted your code a bit, and added why this answer needed updating. Please revert any changes if you don't agree.

Comment: This is the most up to date answer.

Answer (score 1):

You most change your code like this

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, process } = require('electron')
```

Comment: I tried, but was not able to reproduce a situation in which this works or helps. This line will make `process` undefined.