# Process is not defined for Electron's Getting Started App

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, electron, chromium

I am trying to get started with Electron. I was already able to run all [simple examples](https://www.electronjs.org/blog/simple-samples). They all work as expected. When I try to follow the [Quick Start Guide](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start) I experience the same issue as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56632578/running-the-first-electron-app-wont-show-versions): The app launches properly, but does not display the versions of node Chrome and Electron. When I look into the developing tools I see this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at index.html:14
```

However, I *have* set `nodeIntegration` to `true`.

Why is it still not working?

**Versions:**

- npm 7.6.3
- node v14.16.0
- chromium 89.0.4389.82

**Operating System:**

- Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
</head>

<body style="background: white;">
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <p>
        We are using node
        <script>document.write(process.versions.node)</script>,
        Chrome
        <script>document.write(process.versions.chrome)</script>,
        and Electron
        <script>document.write(process.versions.electron)</script>.
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

**main.js**

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')

function createWindow () {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  win.loadFile('index.html')
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow()
  }
})
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "my-electron-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "username",
  "description": "My Electron app",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^12.0.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try to set this value when creating your `BrowserWindow`:

```js
webPreferences: { nodeIntegration: true, contextIsolation: false }
```

A new [major Electron version has been released](https://www.electronjs.org/blog/electron-12-0) which broke the tutorial.
The specific breaking change is a new default value of `contextIsolation` flag.

For more details, see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/27961).

Comment: Is there an alternative with disabled `nodeIntegration`? I am upgrading an old Electron 3 app and I can't tell which approach is to be preferred, whether I need to refactor my app a bit or not.

Comment: **Please see** https://stackoverflow.com/a/78054392/3917091